# windows batch file to compile and run scala script

Tags: windows, scala, scripting, batch-file

I want to write a windows batch file that first compiles a scala script and then runs it.

Somehow when i run the .bat file, it will only perform the first command, not the second. It will only compile the script and not run it.

If i execute the two commands of the .bat file by myself, it works.

What am i doing wrong?

content of v.scala:

```
object v extends App {
println("hello")
}
```

content of run.bat:

```
scalac v.scala
scala v
```

thanks

Comment: @pedrofurla: your oneliner only helps AFTER the compilation has already occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `scalac` a batch file?  If yes, then try making it `call scalac` instead.

If you call a batch file from another, the first one will exit after executing the 2nd one, unless it is called with "call".

Here's an example:

**Foo1.bat**

```
foo2.bat
echo foo1
```

**Foo2.bat**

```
echo foo2
```

It seems like if you run Foo1.bat, it will spit out both "foo1" and "foo2" but it does not:

```
C:\temp>foo1

C:\temp>foo2.bat

C:\temp>echo foo2
foo2
```

To change the behavior, Foo1.bat should look like this:

**foo1.bat**

```
    call foo2.bat
    echo foo1
```